# MigLayout "wrap" not behaving consistently

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I'm using MigLayout to add components to a JPanel in Java.
My problem is that despite adding "wrap" to the cell constraints, it's not working consistently. Some components wrap and some don't - note specifically in the image the last line (which should be 2 lines).

[image]

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("gap 0, insets 0", "",""));

JButton delete = new JButton("Delete");
JButton zoomSel = new JButton("Zoom Sel");
JButton zoomReset = new JButton("Zoom Reset");

panel.add(delete, "span 2 2, grow");
panel.add(zoomSel, "spanx 2, growx, wrap");
panel.add(zoomReset,"growx,wrap 5");

JButton cut = new JButton("Cut");
JButton copy = new JButton("Copy");
JButton paste = new JButton("Paste");
JButton loopSelRgn = new JButton("Loop Sel. Rgns");
JButton selRgnRow = new JButton("Sel Rgns Row");

panel.add(cut);
panel.add(copy);
panel.add(loopSelRgn, "spanx 2, growx, wrap");
panel.add(paste, "spanx 2, growx");
panel.add(selRgnRow, "spanx 2,growx,wrap 5");

JButton duplicate = new JButton("Duplicate");
JButton selectAll = new JButton("Select All");
JButton mute = new JButton("Mute");
JButton shift = new JButton("Shift");

panel.add(duplicate, "span 2 2, grow");
panel.add(selectAll, "span 2 2, grow, wrap");

panel.add(mute, "spanx 2, growx");
panel.add(shift, "spanx 2, growx");
```

edit: thanks everybody for their answers, although my solution was to switch to percentage constraints for setting the heights instead of relying on spans. this seemed to fix the weirdness going on with wrap.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why you're using `wrap 5` when it looks like you need 4. I believe to have achieved what you wanted by simply

- adding `wrap 4` to the first constructor argument
- using `wrap` (without argument) for each last row component when needed

Comment: good direction, just a couple of comments: a) "wrap 5" has a different meaning as layout vs. component constraint: only the former means "wrap after 5 cells" while the latter means "wrap with a rowgap of 5" b) if the wrap is defined in the layout, it's typically not necessary to add them in the components as well

Comment: @kleopatra: Thank you for the info, really appreciated! I'm pretty new to this and wanted to help as there was no answer for 10 days.

Answer (score -1):

The technical reason is the row-span of the duplicate/selectAll button (is that intentional?): you are wrapping the first of the spanned row, leaving the second for the following components. You can make that fact visible by addding a gap to the wrap, like f.i.

```
panel.add(duplicate, "span 2 2, grow");
panel.add(selectAll, "span 2 2, grow, wrap 10");
```

Technically, you can solve it by a newline constraint:

```
panel.add(mute, "newline, spanx 2, growx");
panel.add(shift, "spanx 2, growx");
```

A real solution would be refactoring the constraints:

- move as much as possible into the layout (as @martinuus already suggested)
- make them as simple as possible: as nearly all buttons are spanning cells, a simpler alternative is to make those the norm (aka: 1 column) and split the cut/copy

something like:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("gap 0, insets 0, wrap 2", "",""));

panel.add(delete, "spany 2, grow");
panel.add(zoomSel, "growx");
panel.add(zoomReset,"growx");

panel.add(cut, "split 2");
panel.add(copy);
panel.add(loopSelRgn, "growx");
```

Comment: I like the `split` trick. I was thinking about using three columns, but didn't know how to make the last one as wide as the first and second and also the gap. Is there a way?

Comment: not entirely sure what you are exactly after, but I would try (didn't though :-) a sizegroup on the component constraints in the first row